# Alias "ext.components.MyClass" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable

Tags: yii, yii-components

i am new in yii framework. currently i am using yii 1.1.
now i want to create custom components and we can say than create global function which is use anywhere in the application.
According to this url 'http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/727/updated-how-to-create-call-custom-global-function-in-whole-application/'

i am follow all steps according to above url
but i have occur a error 
Alias "ext.components.MyClass" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.

MyClass.php in the components folder

```
class MyClass extends CApplicationComponent {

      public function get_my_info() {
      $value = '1';
          return $value;
     }

    }
```

Declare in the config folder

```
'components'=>array(

        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        ),

                'myClass' => array(
                    'class' => 'ext.components.MyClass',
                ),
```

And use in the view file

```
<?php  
        $myInfo = Yii::app()->myClass->get_my_info(); 
        echo $myInfo;

?>
```

Comment: Check your file permissions. Update it to 755 and then check. I know its a late comment, but it may help some one else

Answer (score 3):

Have you put the file in correct component directory?. As per your alias the path should be `/protected/extensions/components/MyClass.php`

Answer (score 0):

Write full path like `application.modules.setting.components.*`